# Linq to entities projection: is this projection inefficient?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I don't know if this is going to be "factored" by LINQ or not.

```
 dbContext.Bills.Select(b => new 
 {
      code = b.Code,
      date = b.Date,
      weight = b.Package.Weight,
      quantity = b.BillRows.Sum(r => (int)r.Quantity) ?? 0,
      total = b.Package.Weight * (b.BillRows.Sum(r => (int)r.Quantity) ?? 0),
 });
```

As you can see, the projection has two times this piece of code:

```
    b.BillRows.Sum(r => (int)r.Quantity) ?? 0
```

Question: Is LINQ going to reuse the result of the first one -**or**- is it going to calculate twice that sum?

(*) This entire projection is transformed to SQL, so here nothing is calculated in memory.

I know I could do the following (but... is kind of ugly/unelegant)

```
 dbContext.Bills.Select(b => new 
 {
      code = b.Code,
      date = b.Date,
      weight = b.Package.Weight,
      quantity = b.BillRows.Sum(r => (int)r.Quantity) ?? 0,
      total = 0,

 }).Select(b => new 
 {
      code = b.code,
      date = b.date,
      weight = b.weight,
      quantity = b.quantity,
      total = b.weight * b.quantity
 });
```

Comment: If I were you I would run both versions of your query and time them. If you get a result where one significantly outperforms the other I'd be surprised. If you do good, but if you don't then I'd pick the query that you can understand the easiest when reviewing your code. Better code management should outweigh minor efficiencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will do it twice. I did a mock example summing IDs (didn't want to write up all those classes etc etc);

Here's my query:

```
BookingRequests.Select(br => new {
        quantity = br.BookingRequestCalendars.Sum(brc => brc.CalendarID),
        total = br.BookingRequestCalendars.Sum(brc => brc.CalendarID) * br.Id
}).Dump();
```

Which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM([t1].[CalendarID])
    FROM [BookingRequestCalendar] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[BookingRequestID] = [t0].[Id]
    ) AS [quantity], ((
    SELECT SUM([t2].[CalendarID])
    FROM [BookingRequestCalendar] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[BookingRequestID] = [t0].[Id]
    )) * [t0].[Id] AS [total]
FROM [BookingRequests] AS [t0]
```

As for the performance hit, I couldn't tell you. Perhaps the DB will optimize that away for you. I'd run some profiling on this code to see if it's worth optimizing the query

Your second query looks a bit better:

```
BookingRequests.Select(br => new {
        weight = br.Id,
        quantity = br.BookingRequestCalendars.Sum(brc => brc.CalendarID),
        total = 0
    })
    .Select(b => new {
        quality = b.quantity,
        total = b.weight * b.quantity
    })
    .Dump();
```

Produces:

```
SELECT [t2].[value] AS [quality], [t2].[Id] * [t2].[value] AS [total]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Id], (
        SELECT SUM([t1].[CalendarID])
        FROM [BookingRequestCalendar] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[BookingRequestID] = [t0].[Id]
        ) AS [value]
    FROM [BookingRequests] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t2]
```

In response to comment about a nicer way to do it, perhaps something like this?

```
BookingRequests.Select(br => new {
        quantity = br.BookingRequestCalendars.Sum(brc => brc.CalendarID),
        b = br
    })
    .Select(br => new {
    //  code = br.b.code,
    //  date = br.b.date,
        quality = br.quantity,
        total = br.quantity * br.b.Id
    }).Dump();
```

It gives this SQL:

```
SELECT [t2].[value] AS [quality], [t2].[value] * [t2].[Id] AS [br]
FROM (
    SELECT (
        SELECT SUM([t1].[CalendarID])
        FROM [BookingRequestCalendar] AS [t1]
        WHERE [t1].[BookingRequestID] = [t0].[Id]
        ) AS [value], [t0].[Id]
    FROM [BookingRequests] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t2]
```

That is, you return the sum as a variable, plus the entire row. The benefit is that you don't have to duplicate the rest of the properties (you only have to fill in the second select) - the downside is that `br.b.Id` doesn't look too neat. It's really a matter of preference. I'm not sure if there's a really elegant solution for this.

Another option would be to write a view, and query off that view instead. It may look nicer in code - but may not be worth the effort

Comment: do you know a more elegant solution than the second code I posted?

Comment: @sports See my edit; though it's debatable how much more elegant it is (if it all)

Comment: Ahhh! nice! I think its a little more elegant.